# How to use dimensions in C# Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API?

Tags: c#, real-time, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to get realtime data from Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API (Google.Apis.Analytics.v3), the following code works fine and gets the active users.

What I can't wrap my head around is how to get data from dimensions?

Fx. this dimension: rt:deviceCategory, it doesn't have a metric according to this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

If anyone could point me in the right direction on this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
            var credential = GetCredential().Result;
            using (var svc = new AnalyticsService(
                new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Google Analytics API Console"
                })
            )
            {
                GetRequest request;
                RealtimeData response;

                request = svc.Data.Realtime.Get("ga:XXXXX", "rt:activeUsers");         
                response = request.Execute();
                foreach (var row in response.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (string col in row)
                    {
                        Console.Write(col + " ");  // writes the value of the column
                    }
                    Console.Write("\r\n");
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/Genreated-samples1.0/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3

The RealtimeSample.cs can add dimensions to the Real Time API, just have to change line no. 127 to:

```
if (piShared != null && property.GetValue(optional, null) != null) // TODO Test that we do not add values for items that are null
```

And capitalize the A of analyticsService in a couple of places. Then use as:

```
                RealtimeSample.RealtimeGetOptionalParms param = new RealtimeSample.RealtimeGetOptionalParms();
                param.Dimensions = "rt:deviceCategory";
                response = RealtimeSample.Get(svc, "ga:XXXXX", "rt:activeUsers", param);
                foreach (var row in response.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (string col in row)
                    {
                        Console.Write(col + " ");  // writes the value of the column
                    }
                    Console.Write("\r\n");
                }
```